# Puppeteer how to goto directly desired page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {

  // 1. Launch the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({   
          "args": [
              '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
          ],
          "headless": false,
        });

    // Open a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    // Set UserAgent to Firefox
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36');

    await page.setBypassCSP(true);

    // Navigate to URL
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

When I run the script above, it opens a tab `about:blank` then it opens another tab with `google.com`

[image]

How can I only open the google page?

Or make it go to `google page` from the `about:blank page`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `puppeteer.launch` it opens up a page automatically. Next when you call `browser.newPage`, this gives you another page (tab).

If you do not need an additional page, what you could do is use the one that got opened as part of `puppeteer.launch`. Something like:

```js
// 1. Launch the browser
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({   
      "args": [
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
      ],
      "headless": false,
    });

// 2. Get the default page
const pages = await browser.pages();
const page = pages[0];

//3. Use this page object subsequently
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

Comment: Or just `const [page] = await browser.pages();`.